# Comparing an integer variable in the Bash shell

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, variable-assignment

I know I'm missing something very obvious, but I just can't see it. In the code below, `new_i` variable gets incremented properly, however, when I get to the `if` statement, I think my syntax is off. I looked at some examples, but none show variable set to zero when `if` statement is greater than (in this case `15`) a number.

```
#!/bin/sh
i=$(cat /etc/hour.conf)
new_i=$((i+1))
if [[ "$new_i" -gt 15 ]]; then
 new_i=0
fi
echo "$new_i">/etc/hour.conf
echo "$new_i"
```

When I run this script I get the following error:

```
./loops: 3: ./loops: Illegal number: new_i
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Remove space after `=`: `new_i=0`

Comment: that gives the same error message

Comment: Ah, the problem is on line **3**... What is content of `/etc/hour.conf`?

Comment: echo 0>/etc/hour.conf

Comment: Hm.. Can you cat that file? `echo 0>x.txt && cat x.txt` gives me empty file. To fix it you have to add space before `>`: **echo 0 >/etc/hour.conf**

Comment: @user3308131, why do you think `new_i` is greater than 15? The code is syntactically correct. Try to replace `i=$(cat /etc/hour.conf)` with `i=4`, for instance

Comment: Apart from the space in the assignment you had earlier, that seems to work ok. As long as the file contains a number, and not for example the string `new_i`. Which you could get if the echo to the file was typoed as `echo "new_i" > /etc/hour.conf`. But not from Bash. It would take the string as a variable name (yes, really, try `bash -c 'y=123; x=y; echo $(( x+1 ))' `. But then your hashbang line doesn't say `bash`, it says `/bin/sh`.

Comment: @user3308131, you should fetch the number from file with sed, awk, perl etc. Enclose the command substitution in double quotes: `i="$(....)"`

Comment: (And of course if your `/bin/sh` just so happens to be, say `dash`, it doesn't support `[[..]]`.)

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov, what difference do you suppose `sed` would make compared to `cat` if the file only contains a number. And while double-quoting is a good habit, it doesn't do a difference in an assignment like that.

Comment: @ilkkachu, how do you know that the file contains only a number? Yes, he can leave it as `i=$(...)`.

Comment: The code I run is correct if I change the filename `/etc/hour.conf` to `x.txt` and the initial content of the file is empty.

Comment: If you edit your code to remove bugs after they're pointed out, the result is a comment thread that makes no sense to new readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works - the $ in front of the i in the new_i=$(( line and the removal of the quotes and one set of the brackets fixed the errors and now the scripts works as intended.  Thanks to everyone for their help!

```
#!/bin/sh
i=$(cat /etc/hour.conf)
new_i=$(($i+1))
if [ $new_i -gt 15 ]; then
 new_i=0
fi
echo "$new_i">/etc/hour.conf
echo "$new_i"
```

Comment: `$((i+1))` works the same as `$(($i+1))` if `i` is a valid number. And the code you posted works if I change the filename to `x.txt` and set it initial content to empty.

Comment: Glad we helped... but really not clear how we did it, haha ;)

Comment: `$((i+1))` is *definitely* valid out-of-the-box.

Comment: As for `[[ ]]` vs `[ ]`, the former requires a different shebang -- it'll work with `#!/bin/bash`, for example; just not `#!/bin/sh`.

Answer (score 0):

Try without the quotes:

```
if [ $new_i -gt 15 ]; then
    ...
fi
```

or, better yet, use *arithmetic evaluation* instead:

```
if (( $new_i > 15 )) ; then
    ...
fi
```

Comment: different error
./loops Illegal number:new_i

Comment: -get i think it is a typo

Comment: I used -gt when I tested.

Comment: (( $new_i > 15) gave the same error.... ./loops: Illegal number: new_i

Comment: What difference  does removing the quotes make if the variable doesn't contain a valid number?

Comment: @user3308131 set `new_i=20` and comment out the first two lines. If that works as expected, then your problem is elsewhere ;)

Comment: @ilkkachu it wasn't clear initially that the nasty `new_i` didn't contain a valid integer... ;)